# Select Distinct formatted dates in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a large number of datetime entries. I want to select a list of distinct MONTH YEAR strings ordered in descending date order. For example I want to see

```
October 2012
September 2012
June 2012
July 2011
```

The query needs to be a distinct because there are multiple entries for each month/day.

This is what I have

```
SELECT  DISTINCT YEAR(DateRequested), datename(MONTH,[DateRequested])
FROM    [dbo].[MyDateData]
ORDER BY YEAR(DateRequested), MONTH([DateRequested])
```

but I get this error:

```
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.
```

It feels like I'm almost there but can't get this syntax correct. I am using SQL server 2012 - thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try;

```
SELECT monthYear FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT DATENAME(month,dateCol) + ' ' + 
                CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(year,dateCol)) monthYear, 
                CONVERT(varchar(6),dateCol, 112) orderCol
FROM yourTable ) A
ORDER BY CONVERT(INT,orderCol) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to ensure that everything in your ORDER BY line is also in your SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT  DISTINCT 
     YEAR(DateRequested) "Year",
     DATENAME(MONTH,[DateRequested]) "Month"
  FROM YourDateTable
) 
SELECT * 
FROM CTE 
ORDER BY "Year", "Month"
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4d2ef/4)